# Kendo UI DropDownList - change confirmation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm trying to do very simple thing: when user changes the value of the dropdown list I'd like to display the confirmation. I've tried doing this:

```
change: function () {
    return confirm("Czy chcesz zapisać tę zmianę?");
}
```

and the same thing using `e.preventDefault()` but the value still gets updated.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `select` event instead. `Select` happens before the change, and `change` happens after the value has already been changed.

[Example here.](http://dojo.telerik.com/IzIQ)